# Good sources of protein for vegetarians?

Tags: diet, vegetarianism, body-weight

I am a 15-year-old vegetarian (and I don't eat eggs). Can anyone suggest good sources of vegetarian food with high protein content to improve my health?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some good sources of protein:

- hemp seeds (10g/2tbsp)
- peanut butter (8g/2tbsp)
- chia seeds (4g/2tbsp)
- pumpkin seeds (7g/oz)
- almonds (6g/oz)
- seitan (6g/oz)
- tempeh (30g/cup)
- tofu (20g/cup)
- black beans (15g/cup)
- quinoa (8g/cup)
- soy milk (8g/cup)
- buckwheat (6g/cup)

Do you eat dairy? If you do, try:

- cottage cheese (26g/cup)
- Greek yogurt (20g/cup)

Note that these numbers are approximate (depending on the brand, etc.).
There are many other sources of protein, but I hope this provides you with a starting point.

Here is some more data:

- [Table of Protein (and Amino Acids) in Common Foods](http://www.veganhealth.org/articles/protein#table3)
- [List of Vegetarian Foods High in Protein](http://www.heartspring.net/list_of_vegetarian_protein_foods.html)